# Build Tree from unknown Depth Object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Given an unknown depth of object and trying to build a left & right tree, based on their related properties, the "PARENT" would go to the left side and "CHILD" to the right side.
how to loop recursively to get the data from each children/parent and assign
it to the td elements like below
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf6oQ.png)

what my attemp so far would resulting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0ZiY.png)

The Code :

```js
// My JSON Data
var object = {},
  leaf = {};
const act = [{
    "lotn": "9H042208M",
    "kcnt": 2,
    "excode": "53",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "        ",
    "ryo": 21,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:45:02 AM",
    "linklot": "9K0844080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9H0422080",
    "kcnt": 47,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 21,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 15, 2019 8:23:13 AM",
    "linklot": "9H042208M",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "116902900300",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "14",
    "wkkt": "C990",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 296,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Aug 20, 2019 2:19:39 PM",
    "linklot": "9H0422080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9H069308P",
    "kcnt": 2,
    "excode": "53",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 10,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:45:02 AM",
    "linklot": "9K0844080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9H0693080",
    "kcnt": 49,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 17,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 16, 2019 1:07:09 PM",
    "linklot": "9H069308P",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "116903000500",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "14",
    "wkkt": "C990",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 361,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Aug 24, 2019 8:55:46 PM",
    "linklot": "9H0693080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9K054908K",
    "kcnt": 2,
    "excode": "53",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 19,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:45:02 AM",
    "linklot": "9K0844080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9K0549080",
    "kcnt": 23,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 19,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 15, 2019 2:32:10 PM",
    "linklot": "9K054908K",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9H1128080",
    "kcnt": 20,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "E720",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 301,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 11, 2019 1:29:34 PM",
    "linklot": "9K0549080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "116903100400",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "14",
    "wkkt": "C990",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 296,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Aug 31, 2019 10:37:47 AM",
    "linklot": "9H1128080",
    "groupType": "PARENT"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9K0844080",
    "kcnt": 0,
    "excode": "",
    "wkkt": "",
    "wkkb": "",
    "ryo": 0,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "linklot": "",
    "groupType": ""
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9K084408B",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 25,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:48:21 AM",
    "linklot": "9K0844080",
    "groupType": "CHILD"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9N1235080",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "53",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 25,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Dec 24, 2019 2:25:39 PM",
    "linklot": "9K084408B",
    "groupType": "CHILD"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9N123508A",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 25,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Dec 27, 2019 8:53:44 AM",
    "linklot": "9N1235080",
    "groupType": "CHILD"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9N1239080",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "53",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 21,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Dec 24, 2019 2:29:10 PM",
    "linklot": "9K084408B",
    "groupType": "CHILD"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9N123908A",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 25,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Dec 27, 2019 8:48:40 AM",
    "linklot": "9N1239080",
    "groupType": "CHILD"
  },
  {
    "lotn": "9K084408A",
    "kcnt": 1,
    "excode": "65",
    "wkkt": "Y510",
    "wkkb": "  ",
    "ryo": 25,
    "zuban": "G406100B",
    "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:48:21 AM",
    "linklot": "9K0844080",
    "groupType": "CHILD"
  }
];


function createcontainerView(act) {
  var container = [],
    hasil = [],
    root = {},
    parent,
    child;

  for (var i = 0; i < act.length; i++) {
    parent = act[i];
    if (parent.groupType == "PARENT") {
      object[parent.lotn] = parent;
      object[parent.lotn]["children"] = [];
    } else {
      leaf[parent.lotn] = parent;
      leaf[parent.lotn]["children"] = [];
    }
  }

  Object.assign(root, object, leaf);

  for (var lotn in root) {
    if (root.hasOwnProperty(lotn)) {
      child = root[lotn];
      if (child.linklot && root[child["linklot"]]) {
        root[child["linklot"]]["children"].push(child);
      } else {
        container.push(child);
      }
    }
  }

  return container;


}

<!-- // here is how you build your UL containerview recursively -->
function CreateUlcontainerView(items, parent) {


  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');


  for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
    console.log("row1 : " + root[i]["lotn"]);
    var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbodyTr.setAttribute('id', 'root')
    var tbodyTrTd = document.createElement('td');
    tbodyTrTd.innerHTML = root[i]["lotn"];
    tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTd);
    tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
    for (var j = 0; j < root[i]["children"].length; j++) {
      if (root[i]["children"][j]["groupType"] == "PARENT") {
        var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
        var tbodyTrTd = document.createElement('td');
        tbodyTrTd.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["lotn"];
        tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTd);
        tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
        for (var k = 0; k < root[i]["children"][j]["children"].length; k++) {
          var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
          tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["lotn"];
          tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
          for (var l = 0; l < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"].length; l++) {
            var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
            tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["lotn"];
            tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
            for (var m = 0; m < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"].length; m++) {
              var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
              tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"][m]["lotn"];
              tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
            }
          }
        }
      } else if (root[i]["children"][j]["groupType"] == "CHILD") {
        var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
        var tbodyTrTd = document.createElement('td');
        tbodyTrTd.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["lotn"];
        tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTd);
        tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
        for (var k = 0; k < root[i]["children"][j]["children"].length; k++) {
          var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
          tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["lotn"];
          tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTr);
          for (var l = 0; l < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"].length; l++) {
            var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
            tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["lotn"];
            tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTr);
            for (var m = 0; m < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"].length; m++) {
              var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
              tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"][m]["lotn"];
              tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    //do something with value;

  }
  parent.appendChild(table);
}

var root = createcontainerView(act);

CreateUlcontainerView(object, document.getElementById("output"))
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="output">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit.  Instead of creating one table, Create three tables - for root, parent and children.  Then apply a little css to make them appear side by side.

```
     <style>
         table {
             border: 2px solid black;
             float: left;
         }
     </style>

    // My JSON Data
    var object = {},
      leaf = {};
    const act = [{
        "lotn": "9H042208M",
        "kcnt": 2,
        "excode": "53",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "        ",
        "ryo": 21,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:45:02 AM",
        "linklot": "9K0844080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9H0422080",
        "kcnt": 47,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 21,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 15, 2019 8:23:13 AM",
        "linklot": "9H042208M",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "116902900300",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "14",
        "wkkt": "C990",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 296,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Aug 20, 2019 2:19:39 PM",
        "linklot": "9H0422080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9H069308P",
        "kcnt": 2,
        "excode": "53",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 10,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:45:02 AM",
        "linklot": "9K0844080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9H0693080",
        "kcnt": 49,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 17,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 16, 2019 1:07:09 PM",
        "linklot": "9H069308P",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "116903000500",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "14",
        "wkkt": "C990",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 361,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Aug 24, 2019 8:55:46 PM",
        "linklot": "9H0693080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9K054908K",
        "kcnt": 2,
        "excode": "53",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 19,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:45:02 AM",
        "linklot": "9K0844080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9K0549080",
        "kcnt": 23,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 19,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 15, 2019 2:32:10 PM",
        "linklot": "9K054908K",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9H1128080",
        "kcnt": 20,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "E720",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 301,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 11, 2019 1:29:34 PM",
        "linklot": "9K0549080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "116903100400",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "14",
        "wkkt": "C990",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 296,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Aug 31, 2019 10:37:47 AM",
        "linklot": "9H1128080",
        "groupType": "PARENT"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9K0844080",
        "kcnt": 0,
        "excode": "",
        "wkkt": "",
        "wkkb": "",
        "ryo": 0,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "linklot": "",
        "groupType": ""
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9K084408B",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 25,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:48:21 AM",
        "linklot": "9K0844080",
        "groupType": "CHILD"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9N1235080",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "53",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 25,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Dec 24, 2019 2:25:39 PM",
        "linklot": "9K084408B",
        "groupType": "CHILD"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9N123508A",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 25,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Dec 27, 2019 8:53:44 AM",
        "linklot": "9N1235080",
        "groupType": "CHILD"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9N1239080",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "53",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 21,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Dec 24, 2019 2:29:10 PM",
        "linklot": "9K084408B",
        "groupType": "CHILD"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9N123908A",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 25,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Dec 27, 2019 8:48:40 AM",
        "linklot": "9N1239080",
        "groupType": "CHILD"
      },
      {
        "lotn": "9K084408A",
        "kcnt": 1,
        "excode": "65",
        "wkkt": "Y510",
        "wkkb": "  ",
        "ryo": 25,
        "zuban": "G406100B",
        "eday": "Sep 18, 2019 7:48:21 AM",
        "linklot": "9K0844080",
        "groupType": "CHILD"
      }
    ];


    function createcontainerView(act) {
      var container = [],
        hasil = [],
        root = {},
        parent,
        child;

      for (var i = 0; i < act.length; i++) {
        parent = act[i];
        if (parent.groupType == "PARENT") {
          object[parent.lotn] = parent;
          object[parent.lotn]["children"] = [];
        } else {
          leaf[parent.lotn] = parent;
          leaf[parent.lotn]["children"] = [];
        }
      }

      Object.assign(root, object, leaf);

      for (var lotn in root) {
        if (root.hasOwnProperty(lotn)) {
          child = root[lotn];
          if (child.linklot && root[child["linklot"]]) {
            root[child["linklot"]]["children"].push(child);
          } else {
            container.push(child);
          }
        }
      }

      return container;


    }

    <!-- // here is how you build your UL containerview recursively -->
    function CreateUlcontainerView(items, parent) {


      var tabler = document.createElement('table'); // root table
      var tbodyr = document.createElement('tbody'); // root table

      var tablep = document.createElement('table'); // parent table
      var tbodyp = document.createElement('tbody'); // parent table

      var tablec = document.createElement('table'); // children table
      var tbodyc = document.createElement('tbody'); // children table


      for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
        console.log("row1 : " + root[i]["lotn"]);
        var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
        tbodyTr.setAttribute('id', 'root')
        var tbodyTrTd = document.createElement('td');
        tbodyTrTd.innerHTML = root[i]["lotn"];
        tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTd);
        tbodyr.appendChild(tbodyTr);

        for (var j = 0; j < root[i]["children"].length; j++) {
          if (root[i]["children"][j]["groupType"] == "PARENT") {
            var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
            var tbodyTrTd = document.createElement('td');

            tbodyTrTd.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["lotn"];
            tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTd);
            tbodyp.appendChild(tbodyTr);
            for (var k = 0; k < root[i]["children"][j]["children"].length; k++) {
              var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
              tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["lotn"];
              tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
              for (var l = 0; l < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"].length; l++) {
                var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
                tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["lotn"];
                tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
                for (var m = 0; m < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"].length; m++) {
                  var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
                  tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"][m]["lotn"];
                  tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
                }
              }
            }
          } else if (root[i]["children"][j]["groupType"] == "CHILD") {
            var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
            var tbodyTrTd = document.createElement('td');
            tbodyTrTd.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["lotn"];
            tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTd);
            tbodyc.appendChild(tbodyTr);
            for (var k = 0; k < root[i]["children"][j]["children"].length; k++) {
              var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
              tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["lotn"];
              tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTr);
              for (var l = 0; l < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"].length; l++) {
                var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
                tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["lotn"];
                tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTrTr);
                for (var m = 0; m < root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"].length; m++) {
                  var tbodyTrTr = document.createElement('td');
                  tbodyTrTr.innerHTML = root[i]["children"][j]["children"][k]["children"][l]["children"][m]["lotn"];
                  tbodyTr.prepend(tbodyTrTr);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }


        tabler.appendChild(tbodyr);// root table
        tablep.appendChild(tbodyp);// parent table
        tablec.appendChild(tbodyc);// children table
        //do something with value;

      }
      parent.appendChild(tablep);// parent table
      parent.appendChild(tabler);// root table
      parent.appendChild(tablec);// children table
    }

    var root = createcontainerView(act);

    CreateUlcontainerView(object, document.getElementById("output"))
```

Comment: appreciate, but given the depth is unknown, the 9K084408B had 2 child, how to make them separate into two different row ? cause currently they are on the same level